# WiX. Rollback custom action when is canceled installation

Tags: wix, installation, custom-action, rollback

I have a custom action

```
<CustomAction Id="myActionId" BinaryKey="myAction" DllEntry="MySimpleAction" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="myActionId" After="InstallInitialize">CHECKBOXCOPYPROP=1</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

My custom action does backup and resolved database. I need to do rollback (drop database) when is canceled installation.
I did:

```
<CustomAction Id="myActionId" BinaryKey="myAction" DllEntry="MySimpleAction" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
<CustomAction Id="myActionRollbackId" BinaryKey="myActionRollback" DllEntry="MySimpleAction" Execute="rollback" Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="myActionId" After="InstallInitialize">CHECKBOXCOPYPROP=1</Custom>
      <Custom Action="myActionRollbackId" Before="myActionId">CHECKBOXCOPYPROP=1</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But I was having an error.

If I do like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="myActionId" BinaryKey="myAction" DllEntry="MySimpleAction" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
<CustomAction Id="myActionRollbackId" BinaryKey="myActionRollback" DllEntry="MySimpleAction" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="myActionId" After="InstallInitialize">CHECKBOXCOPYPROP=1</Custom>
      <Custom Action="myActionRollbackId" After="myActionId">CHECKBOXCOPYPROP=1</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

My custom action myActionRollbackId works.

How to run rolback when is canceled installation?
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

The custom action which runs on install and does something with the database should be deferred (`Execute='deferred'`). Its corresponding rollback action should be `Execute='rollback'`. When you schedule these custom actions, the rollback action should go first.

Also, make sure the conditions are set properly.

Comment: If Execute='deferred' for CustomAction Id="myActionId" I had error for this custom action.

Comment: What kind of error? Can you post an excerpt from the verbose log file?

Answer (score 1):

Installation is always done in transaction. when you launch an installer, it first creates something called installation script which is like a to do list of what it will do while installation. 
When we set some custom action as **Execute="immediate"**, it gets executed immediately but when we set our action as  **Execute="deferred"**, it gets added in the installation script, hence rollback becomes easy for this.
Now one thing to note here is that we get access to session in **Execute="immediate"** mode, but we cannot access session in  **Execute="deferred"** mode.
If we try to access session it will give error, which in this case might be the reason for your error...