# How to roll back custom burn bootstrapper when user clicks cancel

Tags: wix, wix3.10

Currently I have made custom UI botstrapper and have embedded three exes into it.
when i cancel installation after successfully installing one exe , the bootstrapper is not rolling back.Instead it will stop the process and user machine is installed with some components of bundle packages.

Can anyone suggest to roll back whole process so that user machine will be in default stage ie without any components of bundle package when i cancel installation.

Comment: If I understand your question, you can find help here : [wix-rollback-custom-action-when-is-canceled-installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543196/wix-rollback-custom-action-when-is-canceled-installation)

Comment: I am using custom bootstraper.The link is not helpful :(