# How to custom action when user cancel Mai installation in between

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, exe

I have installer made up using wix toolset and .Net and using custom bootstrapper or custom ui.

In the bootstrapper project I have chained multiple msi say a, b, c and in all these msi there are some custom action which needed to executed during rollback whether it is user cancellation or failure

Custom action are defined like this

<CustomAction id="c_*rollback" return="check" execute="deffered" BinaryKey="CustomActionDll" DllEntry="c_rollback"/>*

Calling

<InstallExecuteSequence>

<Custom Action="c_rollback" Before='InstallFinalize'><![CDATA[(REMOVE="ALL") AND (SOME CONDITION)]]><!custom>

Problem

When start the installation and say msi a has successfully installed and it is installing msi b

If I cancel the installation during installation of b then only msi a rollback custom will be called

And if I cancel the installation when msi c is installing rollback custom for msi a and Mai b will be called

What i want is that if I am msi b then msi b and a rollback custom should be executed and same with msi c

So does anybody know what I am doing wrong

Tried this soln and soln tagged within it

[Rollback custom not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62175502/rollback-custom-action-not-getting-called-when-cancelling-the-msi-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Rollback custom not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62175502/rollback-custom-action-not-getting-called-when-cancelling-the-msi-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Rollback custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543196/wix-rollback-custom-action-when-is-canceled-installation)

Tried above soln but didn't work and I think it will only work when the custom action fails

Only soln that now I have to put rollback custom in a previous msi for msi b related custom I can put them in a and it will be working fine